# Using jQuery to get an input then searching through an array, then if I value is in array, output the desired answers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

SO, I'm relatively new to arrays. I've tried to solve this with a few variations.

The basis of what I'm trying to do is in the title, but I'll try and explain in more detail.

I have a selection of PDFs, each PDF will be output for selection. Each PDF has an array to represent it, the array contains answers from questions that the user can select an answer for to specify which PDF suits their needs.

I have built a form --

```
<form class="form form-vertical specifier" method="post">

    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="input-append">
            <span class="add-on">Q1</span>
        </div>
        <label class="control-label">What is the Sub-Floor?</label>
        <select name="subFloor">
            <option value="">Please Choose</option>
            <option value="1a">Cementious Screed</option>
            <option value="1b">Anhydrite/Calcium Sulphate Screeds</option>
            <option value="1c">Timber/Chipboard</option>
            <option value="1d">Steel</option>
            <option value="1f">Selecta Screenbooard</option>
            <option value="1e">Any Other?</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="input-append">
            <span class="add-on">Q2</span>
        </div>
        <label class="control-label">Is there a weight issue?</label>
        <select name="weight">
            <option value="">Please Choose</option>
            <option value="2a">Yes</option>
            <option value="2b">No</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="input-append">
            <span class="add-on">Q3</span>
        </div>
        <label class="control-label">Is tehre a height issue?</label>
        <select name="height">
            <option value="">Please Choose</option>
            <option value="3a">Yes</option>
            <option value="3b">No</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="input-append">
            <span class="add-on">Q4</span>
        </div>
        <label class="control-label">Is there under-floor heating?</label>
        <select name="heating">
            <option value="">Please Choose</option>
            <option value="4a">Yes</option>
            <option value="4b">No</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="input-append">
            <span class="add-on">Q5</span>
        </div>
        <label class="control-label">What is the Sub-Floor</label>
        <select name="damp">
            <option value="">Please Choose</option>
            <option value="5a">Yes</option>
            <option value="5b">No</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="input-append">
            <span class="add-on">Q6</span>
        </div>

        <select name="acoustic">
            <option value="">Please Choose</option>
            <option value="6a">Yes</option>
            <option value="6b">No</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" >

</form>
```

The form values represent the question number and then a unique letter that can be associated in an array.

The arrays look like this --

```
$pdfs = array( 
    array('pdf01', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a'),
    array('pdf02', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a'),
    array('pdf03', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a'),
    array('pdf04', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'),
    array('pdf05', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b'),
    array('pdf06', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a'),
    array('pdf07', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a'),
    array('pdf08', 'f', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
    array('pdf09', 'f', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
    array('pdf10', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b'),
    array('pdf11', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b'),
    array('pdf12', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b'),
    array('pdf13', 'g', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b'),
    array('pdf14', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b'),
    array('pdf15', 'd', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a')
);`
```

From this I need to be able to output the PDF name if the input value matches what's in the array.

Any help or pushes in the right direction would be extremely appreciated.

fyi, I'm trying to keep this dynamic so,

```
$('selector').change(function() {
})
```

is, I'm presuming, the approach I need.

Comment: When do you want to output the pdf name; what shall be the defining event? And is the pdf array fix or could you actually change it's structur?

Comment: If I can output the name I can use that as a unique identifier then use jQuery to append an image and styles. Anything can be changed if it needs to be or if there's a better way to go about what i need.

Comment: And the pdf array is constructed in php?

Comment: It is, but they're hand built. I can re build in javascript if needed. Like I said previously, anything can be modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd create a json instead of an array. Something along the line of

`jsonObj = { aaabaa: 'pdf01',  aaabab: 'pdf02', ....  }`

Then you can just put your answers together as a string and look it up in the json object:

```
var pdf = jsonObj[answerString]
```

For finding all PDFs matching a non complete string it gets a little complicated:

1. Build a regular expression. For each not given answer, insert \w. So that it looks like this: `var regEx = /aa\wb\w/` (read as a, a, not set, b, not set).
   To dynamically construct a regular expression you first create it as a string with escaped backslashes: `var regExString = "aa\\wb\\w"` in this case. Then give it to a new RegExp object: `var regEx = new RegExp(regExString)`
2. Iterate through your object and check the keys:

   `var result = [];
    for (key in jsonObj) {
       if (regEx.test(key)) {
          result.push(jsonObj[key]);
       }
    }`

And then you finally have an array ;) But only with the valid PDFs.

But with this approach you lose the advantage of a fast and efficient solution. You could also iterate through your array then and pick only the valid elements. It is just a little less code with this solution.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q8murdcf/2/) for a working demo.

Comment: Would this allow me to answer one one question at a time and then remove the pdfs that don't have the same result as the input?

Comment: I'm struggling with the regEx part. Can you elaborate? @ImreNagy

Comment: Can you post the code you tried? Maybe you try it with quotation marks? Don't. The slashes "/" already indicate that it is a regular expression. Or what is your problem?

Comment: I see your problem. I was a little unprecise. i will update my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don;t understand what you mean by each not given answer - Do I need to write 6 different regEx's? just for the first question? @imreNagy

Comment: No. The regEx I wrote (aa\wb\w) would mean that the user already has answered question 1 (Answer: a), question 2 (Answer: a) and question 4 (Answer: b). He did however not answer the questions 3 and 5, so they get displayed as the regEx symbol \w. And so the question sequence 12345 results into the regEx /aa\wb\w/. I hope this was clearer ;)

Comment: That is much clearer. I have managed to get my regEx to update, Now, using your iterator i get the error "X Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"
`for (var key in jsonObj) {
   if regEx.test(key) { X
    result.push(jsonObj[key]);
   };
  };
`
X = console error

Comment: Sorry had a typo in the if-clause. Forgot the brackets. Updated it.

Comment: I've managed to get a working model, that will dynamically change but, it won't update the results when the other options are changed.. do you have a way i can privately contact you so i can give you the url and have a look? @ImreNagy